# Passing context with bind in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want my panels to re-render themselves when they are clicked.

However, when I perform a click I get the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined
```

It appears that the "this" that I'm logging is in fact the model itself:

```
_callbacks: Object
_changed: true
_escapedAttributes: Object
_previousAttributes: Object
attributes: Object
cid: "c0"
collection: r.d
id: "f5589ba4-a0aa-dd86-9697-30e532e0f975"
__proto__: n
```

I'm having trouble figuring out why the appropriate "this" isn't preserved by passing my context into model.bind.

Here's my code:

```
// Models
window.Panel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: function(){
        return {
            flipped: false,
        };
    },

    toggle: function(){
        this.save({flipped: !this.get("flipped")});
    },

});


// Collections

window.PanelList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model:Panel,

    localStorage: new Store("panels"),    

    flipped: function(){
        return this.filter(function(panel){ return panel.get("flipped"); })
    }   
});


// Global collection of Panels
window.Panels = new PanelList;

// Panel View

window.PanelView = Backbone.View.extend({ 

    tagName: 'div',

    template: _.template($("#panel-template").html()),  

    events: {
        "click" : "toggle"
    },

    initialize: function(){
        this.model.bind("change", this.render, this) 
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    },     

    render: function(){    
        console.log(this);
        var flipped = this.model.get("flipped")
        if (flipped){
           $(this.el).addClass("flip"); 
        } else{
           $(this.el).removeClass("flip"); 
        }           
        return this   
    },

    toggle: function(){
        this.model.toggle(); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The backbone-y way of doing this is to use the `_.bindAll(...)` function provided by underscore:

```
initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this, "render");
    this.model.bind("change", this.render) 
    $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
}
```

What `_.bindAll` does is documented [here](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bindAll), but it is essentially built exactly for this purpose.  If you want to have `this` properly set in *all* functions of the object, you can call `_.bindAll(this)` with no list of functions.  I tend to have this global bind function in most of my views.

Answer (score 13):

I ran into the same issue and ended up using underscore.js's _.bind() method instead.  I queried SO for a response, and it was the reply I got.

Try changing: `this.model.bind("change", this.render, this)`

To: `this.model.bind("change", _.bind(this.render, this))`